# Internet Explorer 8 - new Map() substitution

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

Is there an easily implemented substitution for "var exampleMap = new Map();" that is supported by Internet Explorer 8? I realized that it wasn't supported after I wrote the application with testing in Chrome.

The best solution I could come up with is using [key, [values]], but it seems extremely inefficient.

```
function processData(allText) {
  var numOfColumns = 5;
  var allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);

  return allTextLines;
}

function parseArray(data) {

  var allText = processData(data);

  var systemApplication = new Map();

  for (var i = 1; i < allText.length; i++) {

    currentApplicationParameters = allText[i].split(",");
    currentApplicationName = currentApplicationParameters[0];

    var rsamApplicationProperties = function (entitlementName, environmentName, resourceSequence) {
      this.entitlementName = entitlementName;
      this.environmentName = environmentName;
      this.resourceSequence = resourceSequence;
    };

    if (systemApplication.has(currentApplicationName)) {
      var arrayOfAppParams = [];
      arrayOfAppParams = [systemApplication.get(currentApplicationName)];
      arrayOfAppParams[0].push(new rsamApplicationProperties(
        currentApplicationParameters[1], currentApplicationParameters[3], currentApplicationParameters[2]));
        var myNewArray = [].concat.apply([], arrayOfAppParams);
        systemApplication.set(currentApplicationName, myNewArray);

    } else {

      arrayOfAppParams = [new rsamApplicationProperties(currentApplicationParameters[1], currentApplicationParameters[3], currentApplicationParameters[2])];
      systemApplication.set(currentApplicationName, arrayOfAppParams);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is it feasible to use regular objects instead?

Comment: You have to use a list of key-value pairs for polyfilling. There is no way for clientcode to extract a unique hash out of `{}`, the engine can do that. Therefore you can't fullfill the O(1) requirement, so it is actually impossible to polyfill accurately.

Comment: Basically, I have the Key as a String, and the values as objects of properties associated to that Key (there can be multiple objects tied to the key, so I have an array of objects currently). Are you saying to instead, to create an object every time I find another associated set of properties to the key? Then I could put the objects into an array?

Comment: @bell19026 I don't think there is any other solution other than that. An object where the value is an array of objects is probably the best you can do. If you could show us what you need to replicate, we may be able to further help you, otherwise, right now, it's (quite) vague.

Comment: @briosheje -- I added the function I'm trying to support.

Comment: @bell19026 I've tried to convert the above code a bit. Unfortunately, I don't own IE8 and can't test it either, but it should be a point to start from: https://jsfiddle.net/d5kzh901/

Comment: Map object is supported by IE 11. I did not get any other alternatives for IE 8. IE 8 is too old version and Microsoft had already stopped providing support for it. It is not recommended to use the outdated version. You should at least upgrade to IE 11. Upgrading to IE 11 can also help to solve your above issue. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map